# ¿Cómo implementar un botón de <siguiente> y me lleve al siguiente proyecto de manera dinamica en Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, bootstrap

Estoy en una ruta llamada `/ejercicios/:id` aquí gracias al ID obtengo toda la información de ese ejercicio gracias a los params. Ese ejercicio en sí está dentro de un campo llamado partes, y lo que quiero es implementar 2 botones simples `atrás` y `siguinte` para avanzar al siguiente ejercico que está dentro del campo partes.

Intenté comprobar con un if pero no me funcionó.

```js
siguiente() {
    let idMas = this.id + 1;
    if (this.id + 1 === this.id + 1) {
      this._router.navigate(['/home/jercicio/', this.id + 1]);
    }
  }
```

> El `this.id` es donde tengo almacenada la `id` del `ejercicio` actual
>
> La variable `parteC: any = [{}]` es donde tengo los demás ejercicios
> al que este ejercicio principal pertenece.

Intenté implementar las paginaciones de bootstrap y otras de angular pero no se adaptan a mi diseño pues me piden un `*ngFor` en el contenedor principal y eso me repite todos mis elementos como navs y eso no lo que busco.

Answer (score 0):

Diría que falta más información en el código y la pregunta que planteas.

En primer lugar, tu condicional siempre es `true`, estas comprobando su un valor es igual a sí mismo. Además, ya estas calculando ese valor como `idMas` (que si no vas a modificar puedes declarar como `const`), así que puedes ahorrar recalcularlo dentro del `if`.

Respecto a la navegación, comentas que la ruta es `ejercicios/:id`, y luego en el código de ejemplo tienes `/home/jercicio/:id`. Comprueba que no sea un error al escribir el que no te permite ejecutar esa función correctamente.

Haces referencia a una variable `parteC` que no tengo claro para que usas.

En segundo lugar, que problema estás teniendo? No consigues navegar? es un problema de estilo como comentas al final?

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que lo que quieres es generar urls dinámicas que sean

home/ejercicio/1

home/ejercicio/2

etc...

Si es así, el problema es que no generas bien el string, no tienes que separarlo con una coma si no con un +

Además, asegúrate de que las rutas están creadas en el router module

```
siguiente() {
   this._router.navigate(['/home/jercicio/' + this.id + 1]);
}
```

Comment: Agradezco tu tiempo Carlos. Ya hace tiempo que resolví esta situación, y el problema que tenia en ese entonces era que no comprendía bien la paginación. Utilicé el ngx-pagination y aclarando mi mente e ideas logré implementarlo correctamente.